# Create models from database run time

Tags: python, django

In my Project we create new Databases dynamically. After the create (which works fine) we need to create our models schema with inspectdb. I called following python code.

```
def trigger_after_extract(request):
    # inspectdb
    name = request.GET.get('project')


    command = 'python manage.py inspectdb --database ' + name + ' > api_manager/schemas/' + name + '.py'
    os.system(command)
```

Now this code doesn't work. I already searched the Internet for some solution but couldn't find one.

All I need to do is following: During run-time I need to create a model for a new Database with tables which are already created.

I know that `inspectdb` does exactly what I need but not during run time is there a solution for the it?

Comment: `inspectdb` is not meant as a runtime tool. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here? It smells like a [xy-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I create new database during run time. After that i create some tables and fields in that database. Now I need to create a model from that new Database. I know inspectdb is not for run time but exactly what inspectdb does I need to do during run time.

Comment: are you using python3 or python2 ? This worked for me with python3 :
os.system("python3 /home/simon/mdev/projects/useragentapi/manage.py inspectdb --database default > default.py")
what error are you getting exactly ?